# Latent argument in Stable Diffusion Pipeline (Huggingface Diffusers Library) working unexpectedly

Tags: huggingface, stable-diffusion, diffusers

I'm using the [Stable Diffussion Pipeline](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/v0.26.3/en/api/pipelines/stable_diffusion/text2img#diffusers.StableDiffusionPipeline) from Huggingface, and been trying to start the diffusion process with a custom latent using the [latents param](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/v0.26.3/en/api/pipelines/stable_diffusion/text2img#diffusers.StableDiffusionPipeline.__call__.latents), nevertheless, the result is unexpected.

I took the output (PIL image) of a Stable Diffussion Pipeline and used pil_to_latents() function (shown at the end) to get the latent representation, to later call the second Stable Diffussion Pipeline with the latents param as follows:

```
pipe(
      latents = pil_to_latents(result_image_from_first_pipe)[0],
      *** other pipe arguments
)
```

But at the end, I'm getting a weird and blurry output. If I run the pipeline without this argument, the results seems normal.Does anybody has an idea why this happens? Thanks !

Supporting code:

```
    def pil_to_latents(self, image):
        '''     
        Function to convert image to latents     
        '''     
        init_image = tfms.ToTensor()(image).unsqueeze(0) * 2.0 - 1.0   
        init_image = init_image.to(device="cuda", dtype=torch.float16)
        init_latent_dist = self.vae.encode(init_image).latent_dist.sample() * 0.18215     
        return init_latent_dist  
    
    def latents_to_pil(self, latents):     
        '''     
        Function to convert latents to images     
        '''     
        latents = (1 / 0.18215) * latents     
        with torch.no_grad():         
            image = self.vae.decode(latents).sample     
        
        image = (image / 2 + 0.5).clamp(0, 1)     
        image = image.detach().cpu().permute(0, 2, 3, 1).numpy()      
        images = (image * 255).round().astype("uint8")     
        pil_images = [Image.fromarray(image) for image in images]        
        return pil_images
```